# compiler optimization implementation

Tags: compiler-construction

I just have to implement optimizing techniques on a compiler...
can you please tell me a tool to convert high level language code to three adress code....
so I can implement some technique on 3 adress code..by making a program on Java or any other language

I don't  want to make compiler..just want to show the techniques working

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to demonstrate your optimization technique then why don't you just make up an assembly language, write some sub-optimal code in it, then pass it through your optimizer?

If you're looking to demonstrate on real-world data, then may I suggest you write a tool that converts from JVM instructions or CLI instructions to your three address code format. That way, you can show your optimizer working on a variety of large applications written in a variety of languages.